# Advanced installer is not updating/adding registry entries on Auto-Update for multi-user Installation

Tags: registry, auto-update, multi-user, advanced-installer

We are planning to update/add some registry entries in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION.

Our application works as an addin with windows office applications, on installation based on
1. single user(Administrative privileges not reqd.)
2. multiple user(Administrative privileges reqd.)

Issue : We have introduced these registry changes very recently and added to installer.aip file.

However, When using **autoupdater option on multiple user installation**,
to download and install new msi installer, These registry entries **don't get added or updated , at FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION folder**.

Comment: I think a good troubleshooting start will be to create an [installation log](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-log.html) file and attach it here. So we can check for the installation status of your registry components.

Comment: @herman.smn  I  got a response from  advanced installer team, saying enable support service and non elevated installation, which WORKED for multiUser Installation, However now single user installation fails with  log : 
Installation success or error status: 1603.
Probably because its installation type is 
"Per-machine if the user is an administrator, per-user otherwise"